# Android LayoutDirection set to RTL is not always working

Tags: android, android-layout, right-to-left, android-layout-direction

I have Android application for which I need to force the entire app's layout to `RTL`. I'm doing this by the use of the xml attribute `android:layoutDirection="rtl"`.

It's all working fine until in one of my Activities I need to manually `finish()` the Activity and return back to the previous Activity and henceforth every view that I have manually forced the `RTL` direction on, reverts back to the `LTR` mode until I fully close the app and start it again.

I am using this piece of code in my `BaseActivity` to also force the language which is working fine thus far.

```
override fun onResume() {
    applyLang()
    super.onResume()
}
private fun applyLang() {
    val dm = resources.displayMetrics
    val conf = resources.configuration
    val locale = Locale(FA_LANG.toLowerCase())
    Locale.setDefault(locale)
    conf.setLocale(locale)
    resources.updateConfiguration(conf, dm)
}
```

Notes:
I have tried putting the following code in the `onCreate` of my `BaseActivity` to no avail:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private RelativeLayout mRoot;
```

Initialize your root layout object variable as below :

In Activity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);

         mRoot= findViewById(R.id.message_single_layout);
    }
```

in Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mRoot= (RelativeLayout) view;
}
```

And where ever you want set your root layout Direction to rtl (if your minimum SKD is at least 17). rtl means Right to left

mRoot.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);

Answer (score -1):

add this to your Styles.xml

```
        <item name="android:layoutDirection">rtl</item>
```